# Annoyance - Warning when using Mina 2.x with Spring 3.x

Tags: java, spring, red5, apache-mina

Anyone know of a good way to get rid of this warning, besides increasing the log level? Mind you everything in the server still works as expected, but this occurs every time the server is restarted.

```
o.s.b.f.c.CustomEditorConfigurer - Passing PropertyEditor instances into CustomEditorConfigurer is deprecated: use PropertyEditorRegistrars or PropertyEditor class names instead. Offending key [java.net.SocketAddress; offending editor instance: org.apache.mina.integration.beans.InetSocketAddressEditor@314585
```

The Red5 server is using Apache Mina 2.0 and Spring 3.0.4, but the warning has been showing up since Spring 2.5 or so.

Comment: The warning is there for a reason - it's using a feature of Spring that may get removed in future versions.

Comment: Yes, I understand that; so I probably should have said "anyone know how to fix this"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you probably have something like this in a Spring XML file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="customEditors">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.net.SocketAddress">
                <bean class="org.apache.mina.integration.beans.InetSocketAddressEditor" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As the warning says, passing `PropertyEditor` instances into a `CustomEditorConfigurer` is deprecated. However it's OK to use `PropertyEditor` class names instead.

You can read more about this in the [Javadoc for `CustomEditorConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/CustomEditorConfigurer.html).

The simple fix in your case is to use a class name as the map entry value, instead of an `InetSocketAddressEditor` instance:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="customEditors">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.net.SocketAddress" value="org.apache.mina.integration.beans.InetSocketAddressEditor" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```